# Boolean fuction to all the elements in an array processing 3.0

Tags: arrays, processing, boolean-operations

I'm trying to make a program which shows some circles, and when the user puts all the circles in one place, the background changes. The problem I have is that when one circle is moved to that place the background changes, but I need that to happened once all the elements of the array had changed position..

```java
DragMe[] drags = new DragMe[15];

PGraphics topLayer;
PGraphics toperLayer;

color backgr;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  for (int i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    drags[i]  = new DragMe();
  }
  topLayer = createGraphics(width, height, g.getClass().getName());
}

void draw() {


  background(backgr);


  {  
    topLayer.beginDraw();
    topLayer.noFill();
    topLayer.stroke(0 ); 
    if (mousePressed ==true) {
      topLayer.line( pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY );
      topLayer.endDraw();
    }
    image( topLayer, 0, 0 );
  }


  for (int i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    drags[i].display();
    drags[i].update();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    drags[i].fondo();
  }



  {
    ellipse(width/2.5, height/2.5, 110, 110);
    fill(255);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  for (int i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    if (!drags[i].isOver())
      drags[i].dontMove = true;
    drags[i].offset_x = mouseX - drags[i].pos_x;
    drags[i].offset_y = mouseY - drags[i].pos_y;
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  for (int i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    drags[i].locked = false;
    drags[i].dontMove = false;
  }
}


class DragMe {
  float pos_x, pos_y, SIZE = 25;
  float prev_x, prev_y;
  boolean locked;
  boolean dontMove;
  boolean all;
  color c = color (255);
  float offset_x, offset_y;

  DragMe() {
    pos_x = random(width-SIZE);
    pos_y = random(height-SIZE);
  }

  void update() {
    if (isOver() && !locked && !dontMove || locked && !dontMove )
      c = color (255);
    else
      c = color (255);

    if (isClicked()) {
      locked = true;
    }

    if (isIn()) { 
      locked = false;
      all = true;
    }

    if (locked && !dontMove) {

      pos_x =  mouseX - offset_x;
      pos_y =  mouseY - offset_y;
    }
  }



  void display() {
    fill(c);
    ellipse(pos_x, pos_y, SIZE, SIZE);
    ellipseMode(CORNER);
    noStroke();
  }

  boolean isOver() {
    float right_x = pos_x + SIZE;
    float bottom_y = pos_y + SIZE;
    return mouseX >= pos_x && mouseX <= right_x &&
      mouseY >= pos_y && mouseY <= bottom_y;
  }

  boolean isClicked() {
    return isOver() && mousePressed && !dontMove;
  }
  boolean isIn() {
    float right_x = pos_x + SIZE;
    float bottom_y = pos_y + SIZE;
    return right_x >= width/2.5 + SIZE && right_x <= width/2.5 + 100 &&
      bottom_y >= height/2.5 + SIZE  && bottom_y <= height/2.5  + 100;
  }

  void fondo() {
    if (all == true)
      backgr= 255;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 15 instances of `DragMe`.

Each of those instances contains a variable named `all`.

When **one** instance's `all` is true, you set the background to white.

Specifically, this function:

```
  void fondo() {
    if (all == true)
      backgr= 255;
  }
```

Which you call from `draw()`:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    drags[i].fondo();
  }
```

Instead, you need to check **every** instance's `all` variable, and only change the background if they are all true (in other words, if none of them are false):

```
  boolean allIn = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < drags.length; i++) {
    if (!drags[i].all) {
      allIn = false;
    }
  }

  if (allIn) {
    backgr= 255;
  }
```

For future questions, please try to make sure your code is formatted. It might also be a good idea to use better variable names- naming a variable `all` is a bit hard to talk about. Maybe something like `isInsideWhiteCircle` would be better.